# Can we create template in elastic search autoatically for new index pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-template

We have a index pattern filebeat-7.10.2* and we have template for this.
Now I want a template created automatically for index filebeat-8.6.0.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to install Filebeat 8.6 and run it.

Once installed, you can run the [`setup` command](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html#setup-command) which will install the index template for the 8.6.0 version

```
./filebeat setup --index-management
```

Or just run...

```
./filebeat setup
```

...if you want to install everything (dashboard, pipelines, ILM, templates, etc)

Comment: will old templates be deleted after executing this?

Comment: No, old templates stick around, it's your job to delete them if needed